# How to access USDZ schema at runtime

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, usdz

From what I have read at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/usdz_schemas_for_ar it looks like you can do some great AR stuff like anchoring all from within the USDZ file itself.

I understand you can access this schema with python, but I would like to access the schema at runtime with Swift. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment (February 2022) – no way!

Let's wait for AR USD schemas API.